# Как записать значение переменой в строку по id?

Tags: php, mysql

```
 $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "trainer";

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO content (name, text)
            VALUES ('John', 'Doe')";
        // use exec() because no results are returned
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $conn = null;
```

Мне нужно чтобы данные обновлялись в строке, доступ к которой мы получали за id, то есть когда я изменю в параметрах john на другое имя, то нужно чтобы в БД не создавалась новая строка (так как сейчас происходит), а обновлялась старая по id

Comment: 1. `INSERT` и `UPDATE` - две _различные_ операции. Одна осуществляет вставку данных в таблицу, вторая - изменение уже имеющихся в таблице данных. 2. В _некоторых_ (_крайне малочисленных_) случаях имеет смысл использовать команду `INSERT` c опцией [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html), позволяющей указать, какие данные и на что в имеющейся записи следует изменить, если запись с вносимыми данными уже существует. Синтаксис части `SET` в этом случае соответствует синтаксису операции [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Накидал простой пример из вашего:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "trainer";
$trainerId = isset($_GET['trainerId']) ? $_GET['trainerId'] : null;

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $text = null;
    if ($trainerId) {
        $text = 'item with ID ' . $trainerId . ' has been updated';
        $sql = "UPDATE trainer SET name = 'John', text = 'Doe' WHERE id = {$trainerId}";
    } else {
        $text = 'New record created successfully';
        $sql = "INSERT INTO trainer (name, text) VALUES ('John', 'Doe')";
    }
    // use exec() because no results are returned
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo $text;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```